# Strange "SA ... checker" attributes being added to body tag

Tags: windows, virus, malware

Not sure if this is a good place to ask this question, but here goes.  I am a web developer, and lately I have noticed a strange attribute being added to the `<body>` tag of every web page I open.  Screenshot:

[image]

Notice there is an attribute on the body tag whose value is "SA password protect entry checker".  This just recently started showing up on every single web page I visit -- even those served from my local development server.  I have also seen other attributes such as "SA annotation checker" and "satotalanchorsprocessed".

Has anyone ever seen this before?  Does this seem like some kind of virus/malware?  Thanks!

#### Edit:

The issue appears to be non-browser specific, as I see the same thing happening in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Have you tried with all extensions disabled?

Comment: Is it just happening with Chrome, or does it also happen with other browsers?  Which Antivirus suite are you using?

Comment: @DavidPostill , Yes I've tried with all extensions disabled.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, It appears to be non-browser specific.  I've updated my question to reflect this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Vince do you have McAfee installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because of McAfee. Have just checked on my machine. It checks your passwords for strength level.